# How can i get the content of a for attribute from a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form with 3 fields, I want to write a JS/jQuery function that grabs the ids of the input tags using the for attribute of label since i know the labels text but not the ids.

For example I know The label text "Name" but not the text of its for attribute.

A probable solution: The function takes an array of the known label and loops through it to get the id and return an associative array of nameToId={key1: 'value1',key2:'value2', etc...};

```js
var arr = ['Name:', 'E-mail:', 'Message:'];

function scan(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // get the IDs which are the text of the for attribute
  }
  // return nameToID
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="unknow">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="unknow" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow2">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="unknow2" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow3">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="unknow3" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```js
var arr = ['Name:', 'E-mail:', 'Message:'];

function scan(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var labelFor = $("label:contains(" + arr[i] + ")").attr('for');
    console.log(labelFor);
  }
  // return nameToID
}

scan(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="unknow">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="unknow" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow2">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="unknow2" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow3">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="unknow3" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` with `getAttribute` with pure JavaScript.

```js
const names = ['Name:', 'E-mail:', 'Message:'];
const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('label')];

const scan = (arr, names) => {
    return arr.map((label, index) => {
        return (names.indexOf(label.textContent) >= 0) ?
            (document.getElementById(label.getAttribute('for'))) : false;
    });
};

const inputElements = scan(labels, names);
console.log(inputElements);
```

```html
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="unknow">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="unknow" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow2">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="unknow2" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow3">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="unknow3" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

I went ahead and returned the actual nodes of those `id`s, rather than just the plain text, since I'm guessing that is your final path. If it is not, you can remove the `document.getElementById` wrapper from the `map` method.

Answer (score 0):

**In ES5 javascript, you can write it with a simple 'forEach' loop**

```
  var arr = ['Name:', 'E-mail:', 'Message:'];
  function scan() {
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  console.log(labels);
  var labelText_to_labelFor_map = {};
    [].forEach.call(labels,function(label){
    if (arr.indexOf(label.textContent) >= 0) {
        labelText_to_labelFor_map[label.textContent] = label.getAttribute('for');
    }
  });
  console.log(labelText_to_labelFor_map);
  }
  scan(arr);
```

Comment: This assumes the labels appear in the same order they are in the `Array`.